# Ruby "test/unit" , how do I display the messages in asserts

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit, tap

I have assertions in place in my ruby script.

Each of these assertions also has a message to describe the assertion.

So I have two questions revolving around this

1. I want the messages associated with each assert to display as the
   test progresses. Currently the Message only displays when any thing
   fails
2. The entire test exits when any assertion fails. How do i make the
   tests continue even if one assertion fails?

Sample code that i am using

```
assert_match("hey", "hey this is a test", "The word exists in the string")
```

So the output currently looks like -

```
ruby ruby11.rb -v v
Loaded suite ruby
Started
test_ruby(Ruby): 
F

Finished in 40.555587 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_ruby11(Ruby11) [ruby11.rb:73]:
Text box not displayed
<false> is not true.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
```

And i want it to look like

```
ruby ruby.rb -v v
Loaded suite ruby
Started
test_ruby(Ruby): 
F

ok 1 - First test successful
ok 2 - The text is displayed
ok 3 - The image is present
not ok 4 - Text box not displayed
ok - The picture is visible

Finished in 40.555587 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_ruby(Ruby) [ruby11.rb:73]:
Text box not displayed
<false> is not true.

1 tests, 4 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
```

So in the above desired display, all assertion states are displayed as an when the test is executed. (Something like TAP in perl).
I am new to ruby, so i am sure there is something basic I am doing wrong.

Also i have tried the verbose parameter `ruby ruby.rb -v v`, while running the script. But that does not help either.

Help will be apprecaited

Comment: What about `ruby ruby.rb --verbose`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There isn't much choice for TAP output specifically. One test framework that did was [Bacon](https://github.com/chneukirchen/bacon), which was an RSpec clone with TAP output, but it doesn't appear to be active anymore.

If what you want is compatibility with Continuous Integration, The [ci_reporter](http://rubygems.org/gems/ci_reporter) gem can be used to convert test results (from *both* Test::Unit and RSpec) to the JUnit XML format which will make it work with Jenkins/Hudson, Bamboo, and other JUnit-aware CI servers.

But unlike RSpec, Test/Unit has a limitation where it doesn't report the tests that pass. There's a discussion about running Test/Unit through the RSpec HTML formatter which will include the names of the passing tests [here](http://www.natontesting.com/2009/09/18/get-html-output-from-testunit-by-using-rspec/).

2015 update: You may want to look into MiniTest, which is gaining popularity now and has many formatter plugins and is otherwise very flexible/extendable.

Comment: so currently it cannot be done? I intend to convert the results to JUNIT xml style(to use in jenkins)eventually, so the only reason why I wanted the results was to help me debug while building the test scripts. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: We use RSpec in Jenkins, so that can certainly be done. Test/Unit can too but I prefer RSpec. The `ci_reporter` gem converts the output to the JUnit XML that Jenkins needs.

Comment: thanks mark for your response. I'll mark your solution as the answer. (but i would still love a solution around test/unit :) .)

Comment: @perlnewbie You're in luck! ci_reporter works with test/unit too. See https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter

Comment: yes ci_reporter does work with test-unit, but the core problem still persists. All the asserts that do pass, do no get reported. Only the ones that fail display the "failed assert" (with/without comment)

Comment: That's simply a limitation of test/unit. If you're really tied to test/unit, here's an article showing how to run test/unit through RSpec's HTML formatter for nice output that includes the names of passing tests: http://www.natontesting.com/2009/09/18/get-html-output-from-testunit-by-using-rspec/

Comment: yes, I guess that is a limitation to test/unit. (Coincidentally the same thing is being discussed in the comments of the link you posted). Good share btw. thanks.

Comment: Recent downvoter: please provide a comment. I'm always willing to improve answers and bring old ones up to date.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how I do it, but consider the following:

1. Have one assertion per test. Each specific test should be added for a discrete chunk of behavior. For example, if it's possible for text to appear without an image appearing, then have separate `test_text_appears` and `test_image_appears` tests. Having one assertion per test means that when something does break, you can see all of the assertions that fail, rather than just the first assertion in a test with lots of assertions.
2. Have the test name describe what it should be doing, such as `test_text_appears`.
3. What failure messages should say - I'm not 100% sure what's a good idea here, so I've opened up a separate question: [What makes a good failure message for testunit or other nunit style frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468410/what-makes-a-good-failure-message-for-testunit-or-other-nunit-style-frameworks)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your response. But with this technique, my tests that passed do not still get displayed, and for my particular case is very important. I need to display these assertions passe/failed/error in the form of a report. thank you for your inputs about a separate test per assertion, to not exit on the first failure. That would be helpful.